# How does FirstOrDefault evaluate an inner FirstOrDefault with a condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have this issue where FirstOrDefault always returns the first item it encounters regardless of how the inner expression evaluated.

Lets say I have an array of companies.

```
Companies = {Company1, Company2, Company3}
```

.. and Each company contains an array of employee names.

```
Company1.EmployeeList = {"Employee1", "Employee2"}
Company2.EmployeeList = {"Employee3", "Employee4"}
Company3.EmployeeList = {"Employee5", "Employee6"}
```

Why do I always receive the first company with the following code?

```
var myCompany = Companies.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.EmployeeList.FirstOrDefault(name => name == "Employee3") != null);
```

Answer (score 6):

I run this code:

```
string[] s1 = new [] {"Employee1", "Employee2"};
string[] s2 = new []  {"Employee3", "Employee4"};
string[] s3 = new []  {"Employee5", "Employee6"};
string[][] s = new [] { s1,s2,s3 };

var result = s.FirstOrDefault(c => c.FirstOrDefault(n => n == "Employee3") != null);
```

And the result is:

```
String [] (2 items)  
  Employee3
  Employee4
```

Is your example not telling the whole story?

- Does `Company1` have `Employee3` somewhere in their `EmployeeList`?
- I see you are using LINQ-to-SQL, if this is correct, how do you have a property on a LINQ-to-SQL model that is a string array? Have you added an extension method / partial method to create this array?
- Are the `Employees` not actually `String` (i.e. is the `==` overloaded or similar)

As a start, I'd recommend changing your code to use `Any` rather than `FirstOrDefault != null`

```
var myCompany = Companies
   .FirstOrDefault(c => c.EmployeeList.Any(name => name == "Employee3"));
```

I also notice that you state:

> FirstOrDefault always returns the
>   first item it encounters regardless of
>   how the inner expression evaluated

If this is the case, either you have overloaded `FirstOrDefault` in some way (unlikely) or your inner expression is always true for every example you've tried (i.e. in the example, the `EmployeeList` of your first `Company` has an element that `== "Employee3"` is true for).

**Edit**

Two great recommendations from comments:

1. ingo suggets using `list.Contains(item)` rather than `list.Any(el => el == item)` which means using:

   ```
   var myCo = Companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.EmployeeList.Contains("Employee3"));
   ```
2. John L suggests that the items (`Employee` ?) in `EmployeeList` are value types or similar, such that `default(Employee)` is not `null`.

Comment: Works for me as well. But I would use Contains instead of any.. just a personal preference. Then it looks like this                         var result = s.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Contains("Employee3"));

Comment: Another possibility for the different result is that `EmployeeList` is a struct or other value type, in which case the default isn't null.